# Can't loop through dict_keys in @property method in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging

So I have the following code:

```
@property
def mod_list(self) -> List[Modifier]:
    mods = []
    
    print(len(self.statuses)) #Prints 0??? Update method prints the actual number when called??? Also means it *is* getting called properly when it's getting accessed

    for status in self.statuses: # I've tried calling the keys() method on the dict but that doesn't work either
        print("hello") #Doesn't print, indicating that it isn't looping
        mods.extend(status.mods) # Note: statuses dict uses StatusEffect objects as keys, with values being the number of turns left before that status is removed; StatusEffects all possess a 'mods' property that is initialized to '[]' and can only be made up of modifiers
    
    return mods
```

I don't understand why it can't access the keys of the dict? Even if I remove the decorator and call it instead of accessing it?

Especially when this method works properly?

```
def update(self):
    deletion = []
    print(len(self.statuses)) #Prints actual number of keys????
    for name in self.statuses.keys():
        print(name.name, self.statuses[name]) #Prints normally whenever update is called???
        if hasattr(name, "turn_effect"):
            name.turn_effect(self.entity)
        self.statuses[name] -= 1
        if self.statuses[name] < 1:
            deletion.append(name)
        ...

    for status in deletion:
        del self.statuses[status]
```

Why isn't it working properly? And how do I fix it?

Edit: I managed to recreate the issue below, I think it might have to do with 'deepcopy' in the spawn method since I couldn't recreate the issue from scratch until I implemented and used the spawn method.

```
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Dict, List

from copy import copy, deepcopy

class Entity:
    def __init__(self, name:str, **kwargs:Component):
        self.name = name
    
        self.components:Dict[str, Component] = {}
    
        for name, component in kwargs.items():
            self.add_component(name, component)

    def add_component(self, name:str, component:Component):
        self.components[name] = component
        component.entity = self

    def update(self):
        for comp in self.components.values():
            comp.update()

    def spawn(self):
        return deepcopy(self)


class Component:
    __entity: Entity

    @property
    def entity(self) -> Entity:
        return self.__entity

    @entity.setter
    def entity(self, entity:Entity):
        if hasattr(self, "__entity") and self.__entity is not None:
            self.entity.remove_component(self)
        self.__entity = entity

    def update(self):
        """Placeholder method for component update methods"""


class StatusList(Component):
    entity: Entity
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.statuses:Dict[StatusEffect, int] = {}

    def add_status(self, status:StatusEffect, turns:int=1):
        self.statuses[status] = turns

    def update(self):
        deletion = []
        print(len(self.statuses.keys()))
        for name in self.statuses.keys():
            print(name.name, self.statuses[name])
            if hasattr(name, "turn_effect"):
                name.turn_effect(self.entity)
            self.statuses[name] -= 1
            if self.statuses[name] < 1:
                deletion.append(name)

        for status in deletion:
            del self.statuses[status]

    @property
    def mod_list(self) -> List[Modifier]:
        mods = []
    
        print(len(self.statuses))

        for status in self.statuses:
            print("hello")
            mods.extend(status.mods)
    
        return mods


class StatusEffect:
    name:str
    turn_effect: function
    mods:List[Modifier] = []

    def apply(self, entity:Entity, turns:int=1):
        if "status_list" in entity.components.keys():
            entity.components["status_list"].add_status(self.copy(), turns)

    def copy(self): #I specifically defined this method in the original code in case I need to modify it in the future
        return copy(self)

class StatList(Component):
    entity: Entity
    stat_record: List[Stat] = []
    def __init__(self, **stats:Stat) -> None:
        for name, stat in stats.items():
            stat.stat_list = self
            stat.name = name
            self.stat_record.append(stat)

    def get_stat(self, name:str) -> Optional[Stat]:
        for stat in self.stat_record:
            if name == stat.name:
                return stat

    def get_stat_name(self, stat:Stat) -> Optional[str]:
        if stat in record:
            return stat.name

class Stat:
    name:str
    base_value:int

    def __init__(self, base:int=0):
        self.base_value = base

    @property
    def entity(self) -> Entity:
        return self.stat_list.entity

    @property
    def current_value(self) -> int:
        value = self.base_value
        for mod in self.get_modifiers():
            value += mod.value
        return int(value)

    def get_modifiers(self):
        for component in self.entity.components.values():
            if hasattr(component, "mod_list"):
                for mod in component.mod_list:
                    if mod.stat == self.name:
                        yield mod

class Modifier:
    stat: str
    value: Union[int, float]

    def __init__(self, stat:str, value:Union[int, float]):
        self.stat = stat
        self.value = value

rage = StatusEffect()
rage.name = "Rage"
rage.turn_effect = lambda entity : print(f"{entity.name} is enraged")
rage.mods = [
    Modifier("atk", 5)
]

player = Entity(
    name="Player",
    stat_list=StatList(atk=Stat(5)),
    status_list=StatusList()
).spawn()
rage.apply(player, 10)

while True:
    player.update()
    player.components["stat_list"].get_stat("atk").current_value
    input()
```

Unfortunately, using copy() in the spawn method would result in entities created that way sharing status effects, stats, etc., which really defeats the purpose of spawning new entities

Edit 2: Modified spawn method to use copy and to copy all components, have to add guard clauses now but it works.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing how the property is called, it looks like the problem is the class state rather than coding or syntax.

Comment: Try to isolate the problem in a minimal, reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: a plain class doing that will obviously work,. Without a minimal, full self-contained, example of your problem, no one will be able to help. Actually here goes some minimal help: the property is either not implemented correctly (in the class body), or not used corectly (as an attribute access), or it may be used early in the class code, before `statuses` attrib is actually defined. Which of the 3, we can't guess but by seeing your end to end example.

Comment: You may be able to track the content of `self.statuses` with a debugger or print statements.

Comment: It sounds like you're modifying the collection you're iterating over during iteration, which will generally break in subtle ways.